Get Details of wsdl elements - C#
There is a WSDL service and I want to get every operation, their parameters and their request address (I mean messages, types, bindings and ...).
How can I do that in C# ? I want to show them in a listbox.
I do not know what I should do exactly.

I depends on how complicated the XML is.  There are many ways in c# to parse an xml and there is no one answer which is the best without seeing the xml.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
